# wkhtmltoppdf HighCharts garbled up chart

Tags: svg, highcharts, wkhtmltopdf

I am rendering highcharts to a page using its SVG directly in the HTML page being rendered.

When loading the page, the chart looks fine, but when rendering the PDF, the bars on the chart don't appear and all the text looks garbled up (randomly positioned throughout the chart).

As a work-around, I tried hiding the SVG and rendering a PNG using canvg and rgbcolor. This work-around worked for a while until I realized it wasn't rendering SVG generated from HichCharts in IE and I would have to bite the bullet and figure out why the SVG looked garbled up in the PDF

At this point, I'm contemplating rendering the charts dynamically with HighCharts JS instead of just popping the rendered SVG into the HTML page being converted but that would require significant refactorring and I have little hope it will work since the problem seems to be in the PDF rendering perse.

I am using wkhtmltopdf version 0.11.0

Comment: Do you observe the same error on [Highcharts demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic)? Do you have latest Highcharts version? I mean 3.0.7. Also make sure that you will set delay for javascript, or disable all animations for a chart.

Comment: Thanks, Pawel. I don't think this is a Highcharts issue since the svg is rendering correctly on my page... it's when I try to render a pdf from that very same page that the svg looks garbled up. I've added a JavaScript delay of 3 seconds and still no glory.

Comment: UPDATE: I did a quick copy/paste of some HighCharts code on a JSFiddle they had. The rendering of the PDF worked so I can only guess that there is something wkhttptopdf doesn't like about you just including the SVG. At this point I'm going to refactor my code to send JSON over to my page and use the HighCharts JS renderer to generate the SVG instead.